# Getting old Org version

Tags: org-mode

Here are the relevant parts of my config:

```lisp
** Set up package.el to work with various sources
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (require 'package)
  (setq package-archives '(("elpa" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                           ;; ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")
                           ("nongnu" . "https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/")
                           ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
  (package-initialize)
  (unless package-archive-contents
    (package-refresh-contents))
#+end_src
```

And this:

```lisp
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (use-package org)
  (use-package org-contrib)
#+end_src
```

I should be getting the latest version of Org this way, right?
Well, [elpa](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/org.html) says it should be 9.6.6 but `org-version` says its 9.5.5!

What am I missing please?

Comment: That's because the ```org-mode``` package is built-in into Emacs, giving you the version 9.5.5 (depends on your Emacs version). Assuming you installed manually from Elpa/Melpa, to get it right, add the following line to your ```(use-package org)```: ```:load-path "elpa/org-mode/lisp"```. Another solution is to install Emacs 29, which has the org version 9.6.5.

Comment: It did not help.

Comment: You need to do all of this *early* in your init file (first thing if possible). If you do it later, the chances are high that some piece of Org mode will be loaded from the built-in area and you will end up with a "mixed" installation. And make sure that the path that you add to `load-path` is correct.

Comment: I'm trying to go through this, but I must admit I think it is a mess: I have been using the upstream branch of Org mode for many years, by basically cloning the git repo and setting my `load-path` (no `package-install` and no `use-package` in sight) and I have had zero trouble. I tried for about an hour to get the above going (in a newly created account with no initialization whatsoever) and I still have not succeeded - YMMV and I might try to get this working some more, but overall I think I will stick to my primitive methods.