# Order of different type blocks in org tangle

Tags: org-mode, tangle

I want to create an `org` file with source blocks of **different** types and tangle those in a single file (order is important, of course):

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args  :tangle test.j2

#+begin_src conf-unix
 var1 = a
#+end_src

#+begin_src jinja2 
{% include 'file1' %}
#+end_src 

#+begin_src conf-unix
 var2 = b
#+end_src
```

However, I get:

```
var1 = a

var2 = b

{% include 'file1' %}
```

It seems like `org-mode` collects blocks in alphabetical order by type and only then in the order they were encountered in the `org` file. It does not cause problems when there is only a single type of source blocks, but if there are many, that behavior is certainly not intuitive. Is it a bug or a feature of `org-mode`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with upstream Org mode (updated as of 2023-06-23) but I also cannot reproduce it with Emacs 28 (with built-in Org mode, version 9.5.5). Does `conf-unix` or `jinja2` appear in your `org-babel-load-languages` variable? What version of Org mode are you running?

Comment: org-babel-load-languages’s value is ((shell . t))

Emacs 27.2 with built-in Org version 9.4.

Updated to Org 9.6.6 (it wasn't easy because of org-assert-version error), now it works as intended. So it was a bug after all.

Comment: Yes, that `org-assert-version` was (and is) a PITA. I ran into it trying to figure out an answer to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77635/getting-old-org-version) but I haven't had a chance to get back to that.  There has been some extensive discussion about it on both the Org mode list and the Emacs devel list, but I haven't had time to go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug. Upgrade Org. Version 9.6.6 seemingly works as expected.